# How to remove unusable Ubuntu partition after upgrading to OS X 10.11?

Tags: macos, dual-boot, sip, efi

I dumbly upgraded my Mac OS X to "El Capitan" and I F&%#ed myself. I can't reinstall rEFInd because of SIP. I can't disable SIP because my recovery partition doesn't have csrutil. I can't delete my Ubuntu partitions with Disk Utility for some reason? (It says the one nearest MAC is too small?) What can I do. All solutions seam really time consuming and not simple.

Comment: Are you looking to re-run the installer to fix the recovery HD or steps to install OS X onto a USB drive to let you back up things and erase/start over? It's not entirely clear what you want get done as your next step...

Comment: The simplest way I can either disable SIP or if there is no simple way to do that how I can easily delete those Ubuntu partitions??

Comment: You need a functioning recovery HD to disable SIP. An error missing `csrustil` is an odd failure to have. If you want to try reinstalling OS X - it might fix the SIP issue. I'd try that before nuking the install. As to deleting a partition - could you edit the post to show what `diskutil list` shows when you boot normally into OS X?

Comment: Why do you think you need to erase your Ubuntu install?

Comment: Have a look at Disabling SIP with rEFInd in [The rEFInd Boot Manager: rEFInd and System Integrity Protection](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html).

Comment: @bmike, You said "_You need a functioning recovery HD to disable SIP_" and according to Disabling SIP with rEFInd in [The rEFInd Boot Manager: rEFInd and System Integrity Protection](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html) it says "It will also work if your Recovery HD installation is missing or broken." So apparently one does not need a functioning Recovery HD to disable SIP.

Comment: I have rEFInd installed on one of my hidden EFI partitions. I can hold down the alt/option key a startup, choose to boot to rEFInd. From within rEFInd, I can enable or disable all or parts of SIP. You can do the same thing by installing rEFInd to a USB flash drive.